# How can I fix my help commands (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Currently I am using node.js
So I can't require a command and I am unable to find a folder
code :

```
    module.exports = {
    name: 'cmds',
    description: 'Shows the commands.',
    aliases: 'commands,help',
    cooldown: 1000,
    execute(client, msg, args) {
        const prettyms = require('pretty-ms')
        const author = msg.author
        const authorMember = msg.member
        const user = msg.mentions.users.first()
        const userMember = msg.mentions.members.first()
        const authorOrUser = user || author
        const authorOrUserMember = userMember || authorMember
        const fs = require('fs')
        const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        function getCommand(cmd) {
            return client.commands.get(`${cmd}`)
        }
        for (const category of fs.readdirSync(`../commands`)) {
            for (const cmd of fs.readdirSync(`../${category}`)) {
                const command = require(`../${category}/${cmd}`)
                console.log(command.name)
            }
        }
        embed.setAuthor(`Commands : ${client.commands.size}`)
        embed.setDescription("`<> means required, () means optional and | means it is an alias of a command`")
        embed.setFooter(`Made by 3F1VE#2276`)
        embed.setTimestamp(Date.now())
        embed.setTitle(`Commands`)
        embed.setColor('RANDOM')
        msg.reply({ embeds: [embed] })
    }
}
```

The problem is I cannot find a way to get the commands folder properly.
Here are the files [image: files]

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set the folder list wherever you fetch yhem on startup or fetch them everything in the command(not recommended)

```js
const { readdirSync } = require("fs");
module.exports = (bot) => {
  readdirSync("./commands/").map((dir) => {
    const commands = readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).map((cmd) => {
      let pull = require(`../commands/${dir}/${cmd}`);
      bot.commands.set(pull.name, pull);
      if (pull.aliases) {
        pull.aliases.map((p) => bot.aliases.set(p, pull));
      }
    });
  });
  console.log(`All commands loaded\(Quantity\:${bot.commands.size} \)`)
};
```

You can change the above provided code with minor changes to fetch the folders in the command itself

*Please remember this is pseudo code and would need changes to fit your use case please don't expect it to work out of thr box*

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I typed in the path wrong.